# Property becoming null C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, null

I am facing the issue with the property becoming null when I set the data,

```
SelectedItem="{Binding PropertyName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

public className PropertyName
{
get{return this._PropertyName;}
set{this._PropertyName = value;}
}
```

The problem is when I assign the data in view model

```
PropertyName = new className ();
```

The `"value"` in the setter is null when I debug and check it

Comment: Side note: it might help you and us if you adjust the casing of the types and properties. This is extremely confusing.

Comment: Where is the `PropertyChanged` event implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is by the `Mode=two-way` which states that any changes which are done on UI will be reflected to the property being binded and vice-versa but since you have not added `OnPropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to the properties bound to UI , you face the problem.
Just add `PropertyChanged` to all the properties which are binded to UI,

```
public className PropertyName
{
   get{return this._PropertyName;}
   set
   {
      this._PropertyName = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName");
   }
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {    
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

```
public className PropertyName
{
    get { return this._PropertyName; }
    set 
    {
       this._PropertyName = value; 
       if(PropertyChanged != null)
       {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyName"));
       }
    }
}
```

When you changed value of your property in code UI don't know about it and reflect null value back to your property.